# Elements of vector or map are null when using global instance pointer from within a static function

Tags: c++, vector, static, null

I've written a callback function for another library, but I need to access member functions from within the callback to decide what to do. This function accesses a public global pointer to the instance of the class, which is set on init.

Later, from within the callback, I would like to access a variable that stores chars and pointers to more callbacks. I've tried a map and vectors. Both times the objects inside of the map or vector are null, however, they both usually return the correct size when called. I am sure I am missing something dumb, like the references to the map elements are destroyed, but I have spent hours trying to debug this on my own. I can't get the correct keywords on google to give me an answer, so if there are similar questions then point me in the right direction. This is for software that runs on a microcontroller so each test requires about 2 minutes to flash, I need to use UART to print messages, and crashes cause hard faults. From the MCU programming guide, it looks like this is the runtime problem

> If this address is close to zero, it usually means that the application attempted to access a member of a structure, but the pointer to the structure was NULL.

I've written a little example of how my code works below. The behavior is very odd to me. If I call the size of the vector (or map) in the `do_something` function then I get the correct value (depending on how many functions I've added). But if I try to access one of the items stored then it is always null. Thank you for reading and responding.

example.h

```
//Global object to access the instance from within static function
extern void* example_obj;

class example
{
  public:
    typedef void (*callback_function)(void);
    std::vector<std::pair<char, callback_function>> funcs;

    void add_func(char command, callback_function func);
    void do_something(char trigger);
    
    static void example_callback(...);
}
```

example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"

example::example()
{
  example_obj = (void*)this;
}

void example::begin()
{
  //Set up everything to do with external library, peripherals, ect...

  //Register the callback with the library
  register_callback(&example_callback);
}

//Static func that does something
void example::example_callback(...)
{
  //Have to do this because the args need to match the library's requirements
  example* self = (example*) example_obj;

  //Do some processing...
  self.do_something('x');
}

//Add a function pointer and its command char to the vector
void example::add_func(char command, callback_function func)
{
   this->funcs.push_back(std::pair<char, callback_function> (command, func));
}

//This function is called from the callback
void example::do_something(char trigger)
{
  Serial.println(this->funcs.size());//Always returns the correct size all of the time

  for (int i = 0; i < this->funcs.size(); i++)
  {
    Serial.println((char)this->funcs[i].first);//Always returns null
    if ((char)this->funcs[i].first == trigger)
    {
       //This never works always crashes
       (this->funcs[i].second)();//Evaluate the function stored in the callback
    }
  }
}
```

App.cpp

```
int main ()
{
   example ex;
   ex.add_func('x', test);
   ex.begin();
}

//Example function to bind to the char 
void test()
{
   //Something happens
}
```

Edit: If I add a variable latest_func to the header,

```
std::pair<char, callback_function> latest_func;
```

and then in add_func,

```
this->latest_func = std::pair<char, callback_function>(command, func);
```

to assign it every time add_func is called; it does successfully store the data of the last function to be added. However when I use a vector or a map to store the data, the vector/map isn't destroyed, but each of its elements is. So the funcs.size() always returns correctly but every element in funcs becomes null when it's triggered through the callback (and thus through the global variable).

I wrote some tests to show. You can see size of the vector increasing as I add functions. Once I call begin, the content of the vector (registered func chars) is destroyed. The content of latest func is kept. After begin is called the object is only accessed through the global variable. Is there some reason I cannont access something?

```
[add_func]
funcs size - 1
registered func chars - 6C
latest func -6C
[add_func]
funcs size - 2
registered func chars - 6C, 70
latest func -70
[begin]
funcs size - 2
registered func chars - 6C, 70
latest func -70
[callback]
funcs size - 2
registered func chars - 0, 0
latest func -70
[callback]
funcs size - 2
registered func chars - 0, 0
latest func -70
```

Comment: `this->add_func('x',test)` shouldn't compile.

Comment: Nor should `((char)this->funcs[i].second)()`.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd suspect that `example_callback` gets called after the `example` instance has been destroyed, leaving `example_obj` a dangling pointer. Whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: I think the thing that is missing from the question is the code that creates the `example` object and passes the callback to the 3rd party library, And it would nice to fix the typos.

Comment: @john I have fixed the issues and added more, apologies. The callback is passed after initializing the peripherals in a begin() function, after I have regisetered all of the functions in the vector. The example instance isn't/shouldn't be destroyed, and I only need one instance.

Comment: @Jeb I see nothing wrong with your code. I suspect it's something to do with your environment but I know next to nothing about microcontrollers etc.

Comment: `main` exits right after `ex.begin()` call, at which point `ex` is destroyed. What does `register_callback` do? When exactly is `example_callback` called?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok well I collect the exit in a while(1) loop but it uses an osDelay to allow everything else to be called. `register_callback` points the other api to the function to call to handel event driven stuff. The other API is a bluetooth library. `example_callback` is called whenever a bluetooth event is generated. Events are things like `client connection event` or like `data recieved event`. I basically parse a char out of a recieved packet and want to fire the corresponding function on my microcontroller.